# Use wget command to download multiple files at different locations

Tags: c#, download, wget

I want to download multiple files say www.google.com, yahoo.com and gmail.com at 3 different locations using wget. How should i go about it? Please help me out..

I am doing all this through c#:

```
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("CMD.exe");
        Process p = new Process();
        startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        p = Process.Start(startInfo);

        p.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"wget --output-document=C:\1.xml xyz.com/a.xml");
        p.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"wget --output-document=C:\2.xml xyz.com/b.xml");
        p.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"wget --output-document=C:\3.xml xyz.com/c.xml");

        p.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"EXIT");
        string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        string error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        p.WaitForExit();
        p.Close();
```

This is not working. would like to know if there r any othe ways of downloading multiple files using wget..

Comment: How is it 'not working'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just talking about retrieving each file from a different location, but still doing it sequentially, you just change the URI in the `wget` command to point to a different location.

If you want concurrent downloads rather than sequential, you would have to start three *separate* processes and have them download one file each. These ptocesses could run side by side but I'd probably only consider this for large files (of which an XML file is probably not).

If you're having troubles getting the commands to run at all, the first thing I would do is ditch `cmd.exe` and its standard input. There's no reason why you can't have a process run `wget` directly. Or, if you really only want to start the one process, you could output them to a temporary file and use a single process `cmd /c tempfile.cmd` to run it.

---

However, there may be a totally *different* problem you're having unrelated to what you've shown, because that exact code with three `echo` statements in place of your `wget` ones runs fine, generating the correct output, at least in Visual C# Express 2010.

And, in fact, once I got my GnuWin32 `wget` on to the path, the following worked as well, getting real documents off the net and placing them in my top-level directory:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
            Process p = new Process();
            startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            p = Process.Start(startInfo);

            p.StandardInput.WriteLine(
                @"wget --output-document=c:\q1.txt http://www.ibm.com");
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine(
                @"wget --output-document=c:\q2.txt http://www.microsoft.com");
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine(
                @"wget --output-document=c:\q3.txt http://www.borland.com");

            p.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"exit");

            string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            string error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            p.WaitForExit();
            p.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the proof, the single window partway through the Microsoft download:

[image]

So, bottom line, what you have shown us is not inherently unworkable as evidenced by the image above. My only suggestion is to start looking around at other things such as the version of `wget` you're using, GnuWin32 or CygWin.

---

Now, things get interesting with larger files, as you've stated in one of your comments. If I change all three URIs to `http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/F/C/5FC4F80C-242D-423B-9A11-9510A013152D/Dolphins.themepack`, a file of 12,889,103 bytes, the code above hangs at about 18% of the first download (around the 2.3M mark).

However, if I change the commands so that they have `>nul: 2>nul:` on the end, the download goes through without issue, so I suspect it's most likely an issue with the way `wget` writes its output (without newlines). It also works fully if you don't use redirection on the output and error streams, which strengthens that assertion.

Comment: is it possible to download the file sequentially instead of starting 3 processes?

Comment: @user1650891, yes, just do each process sequentially, exactly like you have (start process, wait for it to finish), assuming you meant only one process at a time. It would be advantageous to refactor it into a function. If you meant one process regardless of concurrency, put all commands into a `x.cmd` file and run `cmd /c x.cmd` in one process.

Comment: the above example works fine if i download 1 file.. so i know that starting a process is not an issue..

Comment: sry.. i didnt get ur answer.. can u plz expalin

Comment: @user1650891, I've added more detail, hopefully it's clearer to you now.

Comment: I checked the code and files again.. When i run my code, it keeps on loading in the browser.. I have 3 files to be downloaded of size:629kb,562kb and 747kb. What is happening is, it downloads first 2 files perfectly but the last file which is of 747kb, out of 747kb only 56kb gets downloaded.

Comment: @user1650891, what happens when you run that command manually outside of C#? And, as a test, use my three URIs instead to see if it's size-related. It's _possible_ it may be generating a lot of output and that may affect `output`. Even if that's not the specific cause, that's the sort of peripheral thing you need to look at.

Comment: it downloads file perfectly when i download each of the file through command prompt

Comment: Hang on, opening in the browser? Are you "executing" these files somehow? From the code shown, it should just write them to the disk.

Comment: Actually i want to download these files to my server and parse these files(this will b done later after downloading the files)

Comment: I tried your links.. all three files are downloaded perfectly.

Comment: @user1650891, then I'd be looking at the size issue, possibly the way you read stdout and stderr and whether a "buffer full" on stderr while you're reading stdout may cause issues. Just tossing around ideas there but it's a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, you're on Windows. wget is part of the GNU Operating System. Unless you've installed a "clone" of wget for Windows, this is impossible. You are probably better off downloading the pages yourself, with something like the [HTTPClient class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx).

But if you have a form of wget installed, what is not working? And how do you want it to work? Your question is not very detailed, you just ask how to go about it, and provide a seemingly fine solution.

Comment: Okay, that's a start. Try and write something to the console between the three lines which are used for downloading, and see if it gets past them.